# never updating record in left outer join many to many relation spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have entity relation as

@Entity Foo

```
//showing only mapping
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "foo_bars",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foos_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bars_id"))
    private List<Bar> bars;
```

and @Entity Bar is

```
//showing only mapping
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bars", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})   
private List<Foo> foos;
```

for saving one Foo with one/many Bars I have a service method

```
    public void saveBar(Foo foo) {
        logger.info("calling saveBar method");
        barRepository.save(foo.getBars());      
    }


    public void save(Foo foo) {     
        fooRepository.save(obj);
        saveBar(obj);
    }
```

data is saved successfully, but things go complicated when I need to update the Foo and add/remove Bars, I have service method for update

```
public void update(Foo foo) {
    fooRepository.update(foo.getId(), foo.getTitle());
    saveBar(foo);
}
```

the update method does update Foo but doesn't update related bars, the foo contains the same bars which were added as it was newly created.

Any mistakes I'm making there?